# How to make in-text page number retroactively update?

Tags: cross-referencing

It would be useful to have a page number like (see page # for more details) that is tied to a specific section or figure, and as a consequence, automatically updates the text to say where that page # of that section or figure is if a change pushes it to a new page. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic command you are looking for is `\pageref{<label>}`.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% <- only for random text in the example

\begin{document}

\pageref{foo}

\lipsum

\section{title}
\label{foo}


\end{document}
```

---

Or you could use the `cleveref` package which will not only insert the pagenumber but also automatically add the word "page" in front of it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\cpageref{foo}

\lipsum

\section{title}
\label{foo}


\end{document}
```

Comment: In a later section of the paper, I put " \label{test} ". Then, I went back the paragraph I wanted to reference that section and put " \pageref{test} " but all it produced was ??. Also, what if I don't want the word "page"?

Comment: @user14554 You have to compile two times.